# How to create schemas dynamically using a single changeset liquibase

Tags: gradle, groovy, liquibase, dsl, liquibase-hibernate

We are new to liquibase and gradle plugin we would like to create multiple schema's

Was able to create this script but it only creates only the last schema 'temp5' and not the other schema's in the list, may be we are missing the knowledge of how liquibase executes the changeset, here is the gradle script

```
liquibase {
activities {
    main {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("temp3");
        list.add("temp4");
        list.add("temp5");
        for (String item : list) {
            System.out.println(item)
            changeLogFile 'src/main/db/changelog3.xml'
            url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
            changeLogParameters([schemaName: item, idValue: list.indexOf(item)])
        }    
    }
}
runList = 'main'
```

}

Here is the changelog3.xml

```
<changeSet author='test' id='${idValue}' runOnChange="true">
<sql splitStatements="false">
    CREATE SCHEMA ${schemaName};
</sql>
</changeSet>
```

This successfully executes but only creates the schema 'temp5' but not temp3 and temp4

[image]

It would be of great help if the community could please point us in the right direction to create all the schema's in the list

Comment: The liquibase update is run at last - so only the latest item (temp5 in your case) you are iterating over is set in the changeSet.
Rather write "static" changeSet since Liquibase is designed to apply each migration script to each databse to keep their schemas in sync not to run changeSets dynamically.

Comment: @sudo thanks for your comment! but our use case we have multiple tenants in different schema's and have the same tables ...the change-set can't be static as new tenants get added we want to read the name of tenant dynamically from a properties file and create the schema and tables dynamically...any suggestion based on this use case would be of great help